# A smarter Entity Framework Codefirst fluent API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to use Sql Server's "datetime2" type on all the DateTime and DateTime? properties of all my entity objects. This is normally done with the fluent API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Mail>().Property(c => c.SendTime).HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

However, I would prefer NOT to do this manually for each and every DateTime field in each and every entity type. (I do not have a common base type where all the DateTime properties can be placed, because the DateTime properties are specific to the entity types where they are defined).

The short question: What are my options ?

The long question: I was considering using reflection and made an atttempt, but it got very messy as is seems like the fluent API is not really suited for this kind of work because I had to call the generic fluent API methods via reflection. Here is my messy attempt:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        var genericEntityMethod = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity");
        var entityTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterface("IEntity") != null);
        foreach (var t in entityTypes) {
            var props = t.GetProperties().Where(p => 
                p.GetSetMethod() != null && 
                p.GetGetMethod() != null && 
                (p.PropertyType == typeof (DateTime) ||  
                p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)));
            foreach (var propertyInfo in props) {
                var entityMethod = genericEntityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t.GetType());
                var entityTypeConfiguration = entityMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder,null);
                var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Parameter(t), propertyInfo), Expression.Parameter(t));

                //var propertyMethod = entityTypeConfiguration.GetType().GetMethod("Property");  // Cant get this to work
                var propertyMethods = entityTypeConfiguration.GetType().GetMethods().Where(m => m.ReturnType == typeof(DateTimePropertyConfiguration)).ToList();
                var propertyMethod = propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof (DateTime) ? propertyMethods[0] : propertyMethods[1];

               var dateTimePropertyConfiguration = propertyMethod.Invoke(entityTypeConfiguration, new object[] {lambdaExpression});
                var hasColumnTypeMethod = entityTypeConfiguration.GetType().GetMethod("HasColumnType");
                hasColumnTypeMethod.Invoke(dateTimePropertyConfiguration, new object[]{ "datetime2" });
            }
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

This fails in this line:

```
                   var dateTimePropertyConfiguration = propertyMethod.Invoke(entityTypeConfiguration, new object[] {lambdaExpression});
```

with this error (Entities.Order is one of my entity objects having a DateTime property):

```
Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Entities.Order,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[System.RuntimeType,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]
```

Can anyone help me out with this reflection approach or better, show me a simpler way to avoid having to manually write a lot of fluent api stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **much better** approach. Unfortunately the approach is based on custom conventions which will be available in EF6. You can try [EF6 Alpha 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/12/10/ef6-alpha-2-available-on-nuget.aspx) and play with custom conventions yourselves - the [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164) contains example with your exact requirement.

To solve your issue with reflection check this [blog article](http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2011/03/custom-conventions-in-entity-framework-code-first-v-4-1/). It describes the code for generating mappings with reflection (there should be related [open source project](http://efcodefirstextras.codeplex.com/)).